# Bluetooth audio device discovering/connecting issues

Tags: windows-7, windows, bluetooth, thinkpad

I have a thinkpad t410 with windows 7. I can't get my yamaha bluetooth audio device to show up as a discovered device to connect. What do I do?

Comment: Have you set the Bluetooth device in a "detectable" mode?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this can be fixed by updating/replacing the bluetooth driver for your machine. It looks like this page has the appropriate driver for the thinkpad t410.

http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-70042